# What are different methods to find the slow decrease in training/validation loss

Tags: conv-neural-network, tensorflow, keras

I am training YOLO network consisting of resnet50 architecture.This problem is to find different text labels on the image and predict bounding boxes

During training, I am seeing very less change in both training and validation loss. ***What are different method / debugging techniques to know where exacly is the problem.*** I am training on 5000 images and have around 23M parameters to train. I am using batch size as 8 and training times as 5 and number of epochs as 50.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the site! My first thought is that 5k images is definitely not enough to hope to optimize 23m parameters, which is why your loss does not decrease.

Comment: Ok, data is not a problem for me as I am generating it myself. could you give sense of how much images i should go for to train 23M parameters.To give more information , I have 9 classes to predict on each image.